# function for converting DMS format to Decimal in Microsoft Excel Visual Basic

Tags: excel, decimal, coordinates, dms, vba

I have problems using Visual Basic in Ms. Excel. I have a sort of coordinates data in DMS format (longitude and latitude) but it's not in a usual format. The data seems like this:

```
 E 103 29 12.4562 
 W 3 9 1.4562 
 N 16 5 32.4333 
 S 16 5 2.4333
```

I want to convert it to a standard decimal format. However, I've never used Visual Basic before. The convention for E, N and W, S are 1 and -1, respectively. I am expecting the output from that data list are

```
 103.4867934
 -3.1504045
 16.09234258
 -16.08400925
```

I hope someone can make a visual basic code to convert this data because I have lots of data like this and I can't convert it manually.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you okay with a formula?

Comment: I'm okay with any formula. i will understand it as fast as I can because I learn another programming language.

Answer (score 0):

instead of VBA you can use this formula:

```
=--(INDEX({"+","+","-","-"},MATCH(LEFT(A1,1),{"E","N","W","S"},0))&MID(A1,3,FIND(" ",MID(A1,3,LEN(A1))))+MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",2))+1,2)/60+MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",3))+1,99)/3600)
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that's a long formula I have to understand with, but thank you. I learn it as fast as I can. I am still open for receiving any answer regarding this question especially on the VBA code anyway.